# How to run batch file, when windows startup on tablet mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, startup

Hello i have a batch file, open url using mozilla firefox
this code batch file :

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-window "http://www.google.com"
```

i'm already paste this bath in path "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" or **Windows + R** type "shell:startup"

in tablet mode this batch not running, but in not tablet mode  / desktop mode this batch running

i'm using windows 10

Help me thank's

Comment: When you start in `tablet mode`, the start screen, by design, will be shown topmost, and startup programs minimized behind it. Are you positive that your program is not running? or were you just expecting to see it in front of the start screen? Also, there's absolutely no good reason to use a batch file for this task. All you need is a Firefox shortcut with `-new-window "https://www.google.com"` appended to the target as needed.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment regarding the shortcut; it would be placed in the startup location instead of your batch file, _after all the startup location was designed for shortcuts to files, not for the files themselves_.